# Render ModelContent directly

Tags: monogame, xna-content-pipeline

Say I have a set of `.fbx` files which contain all my bones, meshes and animations. I want to make use of these in the finished application i.e. rather than converting them all to `.xnb` I just want to load the `.fbx` files at runtime. I've got `AssImp` importing them, `MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline` processing them, but now I have a `ModelContent` object which is not usable as a `Model` (unless I'm missing something obvious).

Can I convert these to `Model` without passing them to a `ContentWriter`/`ContentReader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoGame does not support that, and original XNA did not either (as XNA developer Shawn Hargreaves [blogged](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/08/03/content-pipeline-optional/), "you must either use the Content Pipeline, or not use the type at all"). `ModelContent` gets serialized to the XNB file, and the file is deserialized to a `Model` by the framework.

This is because a runtime dependency to the Content Pipeline assemblies would be useless bloat for most applications (and in XNA's case, a licensing nightmare). XNB is a fast runtime format containing only the necessary data, whereas FBX is the exact opposite. If you *really* need to use FBX models, you have to modify or reimplement `Model`/`ModelContent`.

Comment: I guess this is about as good as we can get if it's not supported. Thanks.